# An insert query in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one is called video_2, one is called vlan.

Table vlan has two columns, one is vlan_id, one is area, it's like an index.

video_2 contains several columns, vlan_id and area are two of them, the vlan_id value in this table is captured in other way

Now I want to insert a column of data into "area" column in table `video_2` if the vlan_id is listed in `vlan` table

Here's my command, but it has syntax error, can anyone help?

`"INSERT INTO video_2 (area), SELECT vlan.area FROM vlan WHERE vlan.vlan_id = video_2.vlan_id"`

Comment: This sounds like an UPDATE rather than an INSERT. Are you modifying a column  of already existing rows?

Comment: @Michael the column "area" in table "video_2" already exists, but contains no data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
INSERT INTO video_2 (area) 
select area
from vlan
where vlan.vlan_id = (select vlan_id from video_2)
```

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO video_2 (area) 
select area
from vlan
INNER JOIN video_2 ON vlan.vlan_id video_2.vlan_id;
```

**Or:** This:

```
INSERT INTO video_2 (area) 
select area
from vlan
WHERE vlan.vlan_id IN (SELECT vlan_id FROM video_2);
```

Comment: @manxing Not my answer, I simply formatted it. But while I'm here... Just change the `where vlan.vlan_id = (select vlan_id from video_2)` to `where vlan.vlan_id IN (select vlan_id from video_2)`. `=` needs to compare to a scalar but `IN` can work with sets.

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
"INSERT INTO video_2 (area) Values(SELECT vlan.area FROM vlan WHERE vlan.vlan_id = video_2.vlan_id)"
```

i hope it will work.